# Health check back-end only spring-boot application (message processing application)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I do have a kafka message processing spring-boot applicattion without any rest controller or api and without any port.

Is there a way I could check the status of the application as if it is up or down?

Comment: Could you push a status heartbeat to an external service? Otherwise, most monitors are request-based, such as Actuator and require its own http endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot has a feature called "Actuators" which configures endpoints for checking system's health and other details.

[Actuators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html)

you can simply add them to your application and you don't need to code any rest controllers.

Comment: The project doesn't have a  web dependency. It's just a message processing system. So, the actuator related dependency is not in the project.